# Get all implementations of an abstract type

Tags: julia

Is there any way to get all implementations of some abstract type? Like:

```
implementations(AbstractString) == [String, DirectIndexString, ...]
```

Would be really handy. Currently I just register all implementations by hand when I need this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you mean

```
julia> subtypes(AbstractString)
6-element Array{Union{DataType, UnionAll},1}:
 Base.SubstitutionString
 Base.Test.GenericString
 DirectIndexString      
 RevString              
 String                 
 SubString
```

Equally, the reverse of this is `supertype`, though, by contrast, if you want to travel up the tree you'll have to do that in steps. Then again, `subtypes` also just gives you subtypes one level down, and you can still use it recursively to travel down the type tree.

If what you mean instead is to find only *concrete* implementations that are subtypes of that type, you can go through all subtypes recursively until you reach bottom, and you can then further also use `isleaftype` to test if they are *concrete* types on top of that.

<sub>Note: A parametric type may return false with `isleaftype` even though it has no subtypes under it. e.g. `isleaftype(SubString)` returns false, but `isleaftype(Substring{String})` returns true.</sub>